# Delete pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c++

I tried delete my structure

```
delete it;
```

and get notification, what this type is incomplete.

> Warning:
>   C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'It'; no destructor called

I have to use forward declaration in header file.

Ok, I think, that create function for delete in same file with iterator is correct way

```
void deleteIterator(It* it)
{
    delete it;
}
```

And just call its from anywhere;

```
deleteIterator(it)
```

Comment: _I have to use forward declaration in header file_ then you can’t delete. But you also can’t new.

Comment: It means the compiler has not seen the full definition of your `class`. A *forward declaration* is **not enough**.

Comment: What? I'm creating new instance using my function It *it = begin(matrix);
begin is implementation in same file with structures.
I need to create my delete function and call its?

Comment: An iterator is never allocated on the free store. Your architecture is crap.

Comment: Why? Its shoudn't?

Answer (score 4):

Calling `delete` requires a full declaration of the addressed type<sup>1</sup>. Move that code out to a translation unit, that sees the full declaration of `it`'s type.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Think about the difference it makes if `typeof(it)` declares a `virtual` destructor, or not.</sub>

Comment: But impementation in source file and compiler must see its, because i included header and in source file this header included also.

Comment: @Dmitry Provide a [MCVE] in your question then, reproducing the situation. There maybe are  more potential issuesto consider, like circular header includes, etc.